# How (or maybe whether) to put both es6 style and csj style files in an NPM module I am publishing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, es6-modules, commonjs

I am going to publish an NPM module but I need clarification on how/whether to put both ES6 import/export style and Node CommonJS require style in the published directory.

According to one website I read both can be included by specifiying in the `package.json`:

```
    "main" : "<common js style index file>",
    "module" : "<es6 js style index file>"
```

but even if doing so, I don't know if they must both have `".js"` suffixes, or whether I can let them have `".cjs"` and `".mjs"` suffices respectively.

The module itself is pure javascript with no dependencies but is a preprocesser tool most likely to be used under Node.

I personally developed it under Node with the `--experimental-modules` flag to enable file type discrimination using es6 style with `".mjs"` suffices.

I am assuming that any transpiling would be done by a user, but the transpiler still needs to find and identify the correct file for input.

Would specifying the files in the 'package.json' like this:

```
    "main" : "<common js style index file>.cjs",
    "module" : "<es6 js style index file>.mjs"
```

be acceptable?